# (Python 3.6) Can't not use variable in module

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my module storing my account information for easy-access in further project.

```
#universal.py

def fb_acc():
    usr = XXXX
    pwd = XXXX
def bank_acc():
    accno = XXXX
    ssc = XXX
    pwd = XXXX
```

However, when I tried to use to put these variables in the local variable, it reported like this:

```
>> from universal import fb_acc
>> usr = fb_acc.usr
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
usr = fb_acc.usr
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'usr'
```

Can anyone help my point my syntax errors in 2 scripts?

Comment: Use Python Classes to access its attributes. What you are accessing are just local variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `usr` variable is defined within the `fb_acc` function, and this means that you cannot access them from the outside (except in some special cases).
Functions have no variables: they are part of code that take some parameters, do some stuff and return a result. Every variable you declare in the function is intended to be used only from that function and to make programmer's life easier.
You should go with a `class` instead, like this:

```
class fb_acc:  
    def __init__(self):
        self.usr = XXXX
        self.pwd = XXXX
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'usr = {}, pwd = {}'.format(self.usr, self.pwd)

foo = fb_acc()
usr = foo.usr
```

Comment: Can I just return self.usr (only the username)?

Comment: Yes. With `foo = fb_acc()` you're creating a new `fb_acc` called `foo`, and with `usr = foo.usr` you're retrieving the `usr` attribute of it.

Comment: Sorry, but it's going to happen again!
>>> import universal as uni

>>> foo = uni.facebook()
>>> usr = foo.usr
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    usr = foo.usr
AttributeError: 'facebook' object has no attribute 'usr'